# How to average data row-wise over a specific set of columns by two factors

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of data with 26 columns. I would like to do a row-wise average over all columns starting with a C by *id* AND *type*:

```
dput(head(df,4))
structure(list(P7 = c(0.266687798848186, 0.243782451327742, 0.256932437720159, 
0.298861598151174), P4 = c(0.198233672667731, 0.0917952258522064, 
0.0911852809187542, 0.0896079263551856), Cz = c(0.236398290801764, 
0.0864552727199747, 0.0745517747485495, 0.141094205953345), Pz = c(0.134887167694073, 
0.0747942533151883, 0.0955856952160322, 0.0351423350784724), 
    P3 = c(0.191077740741983, 0.0671666001582164, 0.15631145309625, 
    0.0784718768200876), P8 = c(0.746777191136397, 0.560405877368518, 
    0.600967378548292, 0.536464030748274), O1 = c(0.178986458890412, 
    0.0630053138978704, 0.0774329882095566, 0.0691776190155007
    ), O2 = c(0.366020592243935, 0.145930065883011, 0.265438304721104, 
    0.161825120181983), T8 = c(0.166974498667532, 0.193021656050489, 
    0.213308929827665, 0.213890447571556), F8 = c(0.263718560854391, 
    0.131907696650378, 0.111178337073373, 0.231875668810878), 
    C4 = c(0.269114234615308, 0.125279019411176, 0.0913937842967784, 
    0.230858661872378), F4 = c(0.231465667185867, 0.161178083318531, 
    0.216487717434052, 0.171471377435883), FP2 = c(0.180752958268289, 
    0.226079727116054, 0.284591837287001, 0.0666576126271971), 
    Fz = c(0.25772461457411, 0.11393640031093, 0.0915436977625258, 
    0.22075971063348), C3 = c(0.251047419087495, 0.116387810932296, 
    0.0658483596391047, 0.217611910888088), F3 = c(0.265273001053431, 
    0.126774002131214, 0.125733221613179, 0.233189075725804), 
    FP1 = c(0.142119646773935, 0.221130756519951, 0.318851412027302, 
    0.0888396971594962), T7 = c(0.249976523730528, 0.0650165785671064, 
    0.108231023089731, 0.235791252265216), F7 = c(0.244199373827059, 
    0.116417055069381, 0.0661299818628654, 0.237627682382219), 
    id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Time = 1:4, Segment = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), TimeLower = c(-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf), TimeUpper = c(180, 
    180, 180, 180), Group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("C", 
    "N"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "theta"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor"))), .Names = c("P7", "P4", "Cz", "Pz", "P3", "P8", 
"O1", "O2", "T8", "F8", "C4", "F4", "FP2", "Fz", "C3", "F3", 
"FP1", "T7", "F7", "id", "Time", "Segment", "TimeLower", "TimeUpper", 
"Group", "type"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

For example I'd like to average in a row-wise fashion all data belonging to columns Cz,C4 and C3 for types=alpha, beta, gamma, delta and theta. And do this by the column id.

Comment: Can u show the expected otuput

Comment: For example in excel I would do =average(C2,K2,O2) in a cell and drag the field to the bottom of the sheet. I think what I'm after is literally average the values in the above cells and doing this for for each row e.g. C3,K3,O3, etc

Comment: The reason I requested to show the output is to double check with my answer..  Perhaps `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(id, type) %>% summarise_at(vars(starts_with("C")), mean) %>% transmute(ave = mean(Cz, C4, C3))`

Comment: Thank you  very much for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id, type) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(starts_with("C")), mean) %>% 
   transmute(avg = mean(Cz, C4, C3))
```

Comment: Looks great! Imagine i wanted to average across "id" to get a mean for each "type". But the length of the vectors for each id is different... How does your function deal with this do you think?

Comment: @HCAI  Sorry, it is not clear to me.  Based on the example showed, what would be the expected output

Comment: Lets take the newly formed average of Cz, C4 and C3. Each 'id' now has a section of values pertaining to this new vector. I want to average again row-wise to get rid of the variable 'id'. The problem is that each id has a data set of different length (as the experiment was of different lengths for each id by mistake). Is this a strange way of thinking?

Comment: Say I stored your last answer in dfm then I did dfm<-melt(dfm,id= c("Group","Type","Segment","id")). So to try and calculate the group averages I'm using: aggregate(dfm$variable, by=list(dfm$Segment,dfm$Type),FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)

Comment: @HCAI I am not exactly getting what you are after.  In the output I showed, there is only a single row and id column.  Could you post as a new question